# toJson() of GSON library returning wrong json

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using GSON library to pass json to server as header.
But it is not generating my expected json.

My Pojo class "TestRequest.java" is like:

```
    public class TestRequest {

        private String mobileNumber;

        public TestRequest(String mobileNumber) {
            this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        }
     }
```

Here is my code to call the GSON class to make json:

```
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     TestRequest tt = new TestRequest("+8801913000000");
     String json = gson.toJson(tt);
```

My expected json is :

```
     {"mobileNumber":"+8801913000000"}
```

But I am getting:

```
     {"aIf":"+8801913000000"}
```

Note: This code was working perfectly 2 days before.

Comment: Works fine for me. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @shmosel i was working fine for me also. But suddenly i am getting this type of dissimilarity.

Comment: do you use serialize annotation in your pojo?

Comment: We can't help you without some way of reproducing the problem. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: @Smartiz no.. My pojo is attached

Comment: Just curious: where did you get `aIf` from? I mean, are you sure you didn't declare it elsewhere?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I also curious... I spend almost 2 hr to find aIf. But i got it from 2 different pojo class.  No i didn't declare elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your pojo class like

```
public class TestRequest implements Serializable {

        @SerializedName("mobileNumber")
        private String mobileNumber;

        public TestRequest(String mobileNumber) {
            this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        }
        public String getMobileNumber() {
            return mobileNumber;
        }

        public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
            this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if not work